# placing adjectives after nouns or using adjective clauses instead?

Tags: word-order, adjective-order, postpositive-adjectives

I have come across different sentences in which adjectives are placed after nouns. I did search for the reason and got to know the idea of the postpositive adjectives which are, in general, used in a poetic way. However, as a language learner, I want to have a clearer rule for that because I cannot feel that poetic sense and do not know when to use it. As in these examples, I do not know why they place the adjectives after the nouns instead of using relative clauses:

> The advertisement is aimed at gullible young women **worried** about their weight.
> [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/gullible?q=gullible)

Instead of

> The advertisement is aimed at gullible young women who are **worried** about their weight.

Similarly

> There are any number of miracle cures on the market for people **gullible** enough to buy them.
> [dictionary.cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gullible)

Rather than

> There are any number of miracle cures on the market for people who are **gullible** enough to buy them.

My question is whether I can use adjective phrases after nouns in all cases instead of relative clauses.
For example:

> I don't like boys (who are) reticent about their past.

> Those (who are) always energetic and positive may find it great to work in this environment.

What is the purpose of doing that? I mean, we may use reduced relative clauses to be short, so does using postpositive adjectives serve the same purpose? As in the first two examples, I cannot sense any poetic factors there.

Comment: The examples you quote are nothing to do with the 'poetic' usage. It occurs sometimes in 'literary' language (Wikipedia gives the example "Once upon a midnight dreary"), but as a learner, you can forget about it.

Comment: These look like examples of [whiz-deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/whiz-deletion/info).